# How can I detect use of invalid properties in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript and I wrote the following code:

```
if (mystring.len > 0) {
    // do stuff
}
```

I accidentally used `.len` instead of `.length`. To my surprise, no error was raised. `mystring.len` returned `undefined` and this made the comparison fail but the code kept right on running. I would prefer an actual error to be raised so I can fix the code. Adding "use strict" didn't help, nor did jslint.

I know there are ways to actively check whether or not a property exists, but that's not what I'm looking for. I want Javascript to tell me when I've made a typo in a property name.

Is there a way to cause Javascript to give an error in this case?

Comment: No, there isn't, as there's nothing wrong with that code as far as JavaScript is concerned.

Comment: FWIW, ReSharper inside visual studio does try to [flag this sort of thing](http://imgur.com/1Q90GQg), along with giving you intellisense for expected properties

Comment: Consider using typescript instead of javascript, that thing tells you about some typos before compiling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope - that is how JavaScript works and it's incredibly useful. Who is to say that checking `len` is something that needs fixing? Consider:

```
if(mystring.len === undefined) {
   mystring.len = "Test";
}
```

The best you can do is to simply check that the thing is defined before using it:

```
if(mystring.len !== undefined) {
}
```

I appreciate the strangeness, and how it doesn't feel robust (having originally come from a C# background) but there isn't a lot you can do unfortunately. The fact that JavaScript is case sensitive makes this even more frustrating. You will learn to live with it though!

If you really really wanted to run some static analysis then you could considering creating a transpiler (e.g. Babel) extension to run this sort of analysis - but it would get really difficult if you ever expected something to be `undefined` which I find is common place.

**edit**

Here's a real example that I'd use where `undefined` is useful. I'm working with a library that needs to move stuff from one location to another. It can't do that unless the original location has been specified, so I might write something like the following, initializing values if I don't have them for some reason:

```
function update(node) {
   if(node.x === undefined) { node.x = 0; }    
   node.y = node.y || 0; // This is the shorthand way I'd actually write it

   // Do some other stuff
};
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote so I can make any improvements to my answer?

Comment: Sure it's useful in some cases but I'm looking for something to help me if I type `mystring.legnth` (note typo).

Comment: @GraemePerrow : Yeah appreciate that, but as I was trying to point out in the first part of my answer - how can the JavaScript engine possibly know that there's an error there? Unfortunately a property being undefined is a common use case (e.g. I've not yet initialized a value)

Comment: @GraemePerrow But what if you had a property called `len` or something of that nature? It's impossible to find a "typo" when there's no indication of wether or not that property is valid

Comment: OK, fair enough. I guess I will simply have to be more vigilant. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"use strict" (in my experience) is used so that variables that aren't explicitly declared/instantiated that are then referenced will throw errors (else, JS would just make a new var on the fly). So that wouldn't help here.

This sounds like an error that would typically be picked up by a compiler in other languages, but since JS is interpreted, you won't have that kind of explicit error checking unless you're in a beefy IDE. Are you using a text editor or something to write JS?

Comment: All modern browsers compile JS now. The issue isn't interpreted vs. compiled. It's a language design issue. JS does not consider it an error to access a property that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not the way JavaScript considers your above code. Every variable in JS is an object. So, when you do `mystring.len`, its actually trying to access the `len` property of `mystring` obj and when it doesn't find that property, it will return `undefined` - which is how it should be. Thats why you will not be able to find any error using JSLint.

Just to give you an example -

```
var myObj = {name: 'Hello', id: 1};
console.log(myObj.name);   // Returns 'Hello'
console.log(myObj.text);   // 'undefined'
```

In order to prevent such code from giving you any errors, you can easily use the [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method like follows-

```
if(myObj.hasOwnProperty('text')) doSomething();
```

Since `myObj` doesn't have any property `text`, the `doSomething()` function will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

This is the behaviour of JavaScript as mentioned by many/all answers. However there is an option to prevent new properties you might want to try:

`Object.seal` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is JavaScript is not ment to be typesafe...You shouldn't check it, but if you still want to check you can do it by:

```
if ('len' in mystring){
}
```

You should look into Typescript if you ask this question...